# ASP.NET project won't run after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio

I just upgraded my system from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. I have a VB ASP.NET project that I've been working on in Visual Studio 2015. Before upgrading the OS everything worked fine. Now, when I try to debug the project I get an error message that says `Unable to connect to the configured development Web server.` The URL for the project is `http://localhost:55550`. My co-workers have made the same upgrade without any issues. What do I need to do to get the debugger to launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Visual Studio as Administrator by Right Click.

Comment: This only worked after I deleted my .vs folder.